# URL Changes (Host is not changing)

Tags: url

I have a site that I'm working on for the Boy Scouts: LHCBSA.info, they have a current site: LHCBSA.org. We are ready (almost) to switch over to the new site (LHCBSA.org would then point to the host for LHCBSA.info). When we are ready to do this I will simply change the DNS recorded for LHCBSA.org (no problem there, just changing where the @ record points to). My question is this... what will I need (if anything) to change in EE to make sure that when someone is visiting our site they will always have a .org address (we are keeping the .info address, i just don't want any one to use it)? EE was setup using the .info address so I'm assuming that after i change over to the .org address there will be something i will need to change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nicholas,

The easiest thing for your to do is to change all your relevant paths/urls using either [Deploy Helper $15](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/deeploy-helper) or [Reelocate (free)](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/reelocate).  My presonal preference is for Deploy Helper.

If you've set your site up using a multi environment such as the [FocusLab Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) set up then there'll be nothing you need to do as everything will just work.